# error downloading R - ERROR: R_HOME ('/usr/lib/R') not found

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, rstudio

I was using normal r and rstudio on the computer but I had to uninstall it. When installing again it even downloads without problems but does not run.

When I search in terminal R --version gives me this error: /usr/bin/R: line 249: /usr/lib/R/etc/ldpaths: No such file or directory
ERROR: R_HOME ('/usr/lib/R') not found

Comment: What OS version are you using? How exactly did you install R?

Comment: i'm using ubuntu version. I intaled conform the instructions of the site https://cran.r-project.org/